# CSS/Shopify styling

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

I am working on a Shopify template for someone and am still learning both liquid and HTML, javascript really.

I am struggling to align the logo on this page...

**https://phoenixapparel.co.uk/password**

At the moment I am using inline style tags to do this as it should be a simple edit, its very basic but I would appreciate any help.

This is the liquid template with the CSS;

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% layout 'password' %}
    <div>
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0490/5022/2756/files/VECTOR_PHOENIX.svg?v=1601726832" style="display: block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
      <h1 style="margin-left: auto;margin-right:auto;font-weight:900;color:black;text-align:center;">Coming Soon...</h1>
    </div
    {% comment %}
    {% section 'password-content' %}
    The contents of the password.liquid templates can be found in /sections
    {% endcomment %}
    {% section 'password-footer' %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Seems dumb to post on here, but nothing I have tried/found seems to be working so anything would be helpful.

Comment: Showing us the Shopify template is of little use to us in your question, which relies upon your generated HTML and CSS. Please, can you show us the "*[mcve]*"  HTML and CSS that's generated once the script/templating has been run?

Comment: The context of a shopify template was relevant to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to align the logo in middle add a class on that div and use display flex to align it to middle or any  place you want
and don't put inline style. there should be a style.scss file in assets folder in shopify use that to add CSS

```
.logo-align {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a class to the div `<div class="logo-align>...</div>`

in css :

```
.logo-align {
  width: the width you want;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Don't forget the width otherwise it's not going to work